# ReplayGain in Rhythmbox has hardly a noticeable effect

Tags: sound, 18.04, rhythmbox

I use Rhythmbox with the ReplayGain plugin activated. However, when I play a few MP3s from my library, volume appears to vary noticeably between tracks, which seems to indicate ReplayGain isn’t set up correctly.

I remember Winamp on Windows required scanning all files in advance and tagging them with their loudness. The player would use that information to determine the correction to apply.

Does Rhythmbox work in the same way? If so, what tools are available to scan and tag MP3 files? If not, what could be causing the behavior I’m seeing?

Comment: I have the same problem with Rhythmbox. I added replaygain tags to my entire library (using `mp3gain`, `vorbisgain`, and `metaflac`), and despite that, I still get significant perceived volume differences between songs (even of the same filetype)...

Answer (score 0):

The ReplayGain plugin uses the rgvolume and rglimiter elements to process ReplayGain tags and adjust the output volume accordingly.

Rhythmbox determines the fallback gain used for tracks that don't provide ReplayGain tags by calculating the mean of the last 10 non-fallback gain levels.

You may tag your files (`eyeD3`) with gain informations given by `mp3gain`.

Here is an example script wich can help you : [Add ReplayGain information to id3 tags of mp3 files](https://gist.github.com/hinrik/269090)

---

*Personnal opinion : replaygain do not preserve sound dynamic range and can cause ears to bleed...*